# Is it safe to return a local pointer that is set to substring of the function's parameter?

Tags: c, function, pointers, return

I searched awhile and couldn't find a similar question.
(it was hard enough coming up with a title to this question that makes sense)

While writing a function that gets the filename from a path, I realized that maybe I could write it without having to allocate memory for the destination buffer by returning a pointer within the passed path parameter.

My question is, is it safe to return the pointer within the passed path parameter like this? I know it's undefined behavior to return a pointer to a local, but what about this case? Or is there a different preferred way to do this (without having to allocate a destination string)?

```
char *getFileFromPath(char *path, char slash)
{
    char *file = path;
    size_t len = strnlen(path, MAX_PATH);
    if (len == MAX_PATH)
        return NULL;

    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (path[i] == slash)
            break;

    if (i + 1 < len - 1)
        file = (path + i + 1);

    return file;
}

char *path = "some/path/to/file.txt";
char *file = getFileFromPath(path, '/');
```

Comment: In part, it depends on whether you want to worry about names such as `"/usr/local/bin/"` with a trailing slash.  The simple minded version uses: `char *file = strrchr(path, slash); if (file == 0) return path; else if (file[1] != '\0') return file + 1; else { …trailing slash; search backwards, perhaps, carefully… }` to cover the most common cases.  Note that you should not modify the string that `path` points at because it is a read-only string literal (or, at least, a string literal that should be treated as read-only).

Comment: most of the string functions of C such as strcpy() or strcat() return the pointer of the destination buffer for the string.  strtok() also returns a pointer that is either to a substring of the string being broken into tokens or the NULL pointer.

Comment: @RichardChambers `strtok()` modifies the string, you can't use it on a string literal, the other functions require a `const char *` to be passed, that's why I recommended that, in my answer, and also because if you don't use the `const` qualifier you may modify the string inside the function, and remeber that you are passing an unmodifable string literal to it, so for it to be safer, you should ensure that the function can't modify the argument, nor the returned pointer.

Comment: @iharob, <sigh> yes I know. The question was about returning a pointer to a substring and I was pointing out that the C Standard Library does that with several examples from the library. By the way const does not prevent you from modifying in a function so I would not put much faith in const when programming in C.  It is more of a guideline than actual rules.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, it just makes the compiler complain, so prevents the possible mistake, but of course you still can cast away the `const`, though you should do it conciously. Quoting myself _`and also because if you don't use the const qualifier you may modify the string inside the function`_ i should have said, accidentally.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, returning any pointer is safe.  The unsafe thing is if the caller attempts to dereference the pointer but the pointed-to object is already deallocated.

In your example, it should be reasonable to expect that a caller of the function will have the argument it passed to the function handy as long as it needs the return value.  And if the argument is to be deleted earlier, the caller can always make its own copy of the relevant sub-string.

So yes, returning a pointer into a buffer that was passed as an argument is safe as long as you clearly document it.  This is also important because your users must remember *not* to `free` the pointer your function returns.

Doing so is not at all uncommon.  For example, the standard library's [`memchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memchr) function does exactly this and it is hard to imagine how it could be written to not do so.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning a local variable, the pointer you return points to the original data passed as the `path` pointer, it is similar to incrementing the pointer without using the function, so it's safe.

I would recommend to mark the parameter `const`, as well as the return value something like

```
const char *getFileFromPath(const char *path, char slash)
{
    const char *file = path;
    size_t len = strnlen(path, MAX_PATH);
    size_t i;

    if (len == MAX_PATH)
        return NULL;

    for (i = len ; (i > 0) && (path[--i] != slash) ; );

    if (i + 1 < len - 1)
        file = (path + i + 1);

    return file;
}
```

also, notice that `size_t` is `unsigned` so `i >= 0` is always true.

Comment: Or use: `size_t i; for (i = len; i > 0; ) { if (path[--i] == slash) break; }` — but your point about not overflowing by decrementing an unsigned 0 is valid.  The code will need to worry about names like `"/"` (the root directory) and `"/usr/bin/"` too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are absolutely right, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! To additionally support `"/"`, `"/usr/bin/"` and `""`, change `if (i + 1 < len - 1)` to `if (i + 1 <= len)`, then it will return empty string for those cases.